# Set Cell-Color inside DataGridTemplateColumn in code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight

This is my `DataGridTemplateColumn`

```
 DataGridTemplateColumn dgt = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

            dgt.CellTemplate = (System.Windows.DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(@"<DataTemplate 
           xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007' 
           xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>

          <CheckBox></CheckBox> </DataTemplate>");
```

How can i set the color in code behind? `dgt.` doesn't show any option for the `Background` or `Foreground`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone needs the answer this is what i did:

```
<Grid Backgorund=""Green"">
  <CheckBox />
</Grid>
```

So instead of using `""` use `"""""`